# how to check if already logged in perforce from command line

Tags: perforce

I want command to check if I am already logged in perforce, which returns 0 if I am logged in, otherwise some non-zero value to represent error. how to achieve this from command line?

Comment: `p4 login -s` The '-s' is for 'status', and it will tell you if you are logged in or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`p4 help login` says:

```
p4 login [-a -p] [-h <host>] [user]
p4 login [-s]

[...]

The -s flag displays the status of the current ticket (if there is one).
```

Additionally, empirical testing shows that running `p4 login -s` while logged in returns an exit code of 0, and running it while not logged in returns an exit code of 1.

Comment: FWIW, version 2016.2 of `p4` will automatically prompt to log in if necessary when running commands.